# R side by side barplot, scale bar by bin size

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to scale the barplot bar width by my bin size (colnames) to show skewness of the data (e.g., the 11-10 bin will be narrower than the 251-500 bin). I am using a side by side barplot, using rownames as my groups (A, B). It seems that the width= argument is only taking the first 2 width values, and assigning one to each group, as opposed to assigning the width values to each bar individually. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
df <- rbind(runif(10,0,1), runif(10,0,1))
rownames(df) <- c("A", "B")
colnames(df) <- c("0", "1-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-75",    "76-125", "126-250", "251-500") 
bar_width = rep(c(1, rep(10,5), 25, 50, 125, 250), each=2)

barplot(df, width=bar_width, beside=T)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but this might be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482165/specify-spaces-between-bars-in-barplot/21421113

Comment: Strictly speaking, `df` here is a matrix, not a data.frame as the name implies.

Comment: @thelatemail that is helpful. Still seems pretty messy, perhaps there's a better way? I should be able to workaround with that. Thank you

Comment: -ish: `library(tidyverse); df %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column('var') %>% gather(range, value, -var) %>% mutate(range = factor(range, levels = unique(range)), bar_width = scales::rescale(bar_width, to = c(.1, 1))) %>% ggplot(aes(x = range, y = value, width = bar_width, fill = var)) + geom_col()`

Comment: @alistaire this is nice. I'll need to work to get them side by side, but that's a nice approach

Comment: You can use `position = 'dodge'` or some variation of `position = position_dodge(.5)` in `geom_col`, but it won't give you bar nicely aligned to the center, annoyingly. There might be a way to fake it with one of the other geoms which can make rectangles, but I suspect it'd be a lot more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt in base R plotting:

```
bp <- barplot(c(df), width=bar_width, 
        space=rep(c(40,0),ncol(df))/mean(bar_width), col=gray.colors(nrow(df)))
axis(1, at=colMeans(matrix(bp,nrow=2)), labels=colnames(df),
     lwd=0, lwd.tick=1, cex.axis=0.7, las=2)
```

[image]